# Show SQL Server table that created with SMO in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I am using this class to create a SQL Server database and table. I want actually to create a database and some tables in it and then show one table in a dataGridView in my Windows Forms application.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    class SqlServerController
    {
        //ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection("MSSQLSERVER", "sysAdmin", "");
        private Server m_server=null;

        public SqlServerController (string server)
        {
            m_server = new Server(server);
        }

        public void AttachDatabase (string database, StringCollection files,AttachOptions options)
        {
            m_server.AttachDatabase(database, files, options);
        }

        public void AddBackupDevice(string name)
        {
            BackupDevice device = new BackupDevice(m_server,name);
            m_server.BackupDevices.Add(device);
        }

        public string GetServerVersion(string serverName)
        {
            return m_server.PingSqlServerVersion(serverName).ToString();
        }

        public int CountActiveConnections(string database)
        {
            return m_server.GetActiveDBConnectionCount(database);
        }

        public void DeleteDatabase (string database)
        {
            m_server.KillDatabase(database);
        }

        public void DetachDatabse (string database, bool updatestatistics,bool removeFullTextIndex)
        {
            m_server.DetachDatabase(database, updatestatistics, removeFullTextIndex);
        }

        public void CreateDatabse (string database)
        {
            Database db = new Database(m_server, database);
            db.Create();
        }

        public void CreateTable(string database, string table, List<Column> ColumnList,List<Index> IndexList)
        {
            Database db = m_server.Databases[database];
            Table newTable = new Table(db, table);

            foreach (Column column in ColumnList)
                newTable.Columns.Add(column);

            if (IndexList !=null)
            {
                foreach (Index index in IndexList)
                    newTable.Indexes.Add(index);
            }

            newTable.Create();
        }

        public Column CreateColumn (string name, DataType type, string @default,bool isIdentity,bool nullable)
        {
            Column column = new Column();
            column.DataType = type;
            column.Default = @default;
            column.Identity = isIdentity;
            column.Nullable = nullable;

            return column;
        }

        public Index CreateIndex(string name, bool isClustered, IndexKeyType type,string[] columnNameList)
        {
            Index index = new Index();

            index.Name = name;
            index.IndexKeyType = type;
            index.IsClustered = isClustered;

            foreach (string columnName in columnNameList)
                index.IndexedColumns.Add(new IndexedColumn(index, columnName));

            return index;
        }

    }
}
```

Now I want to show one of the tables that I created in a DataGridView. How can I do that??

Also I have used this code below in an event trigger on "create Database" button's click event.

```
private void btnCreateDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlServerController SQL = new SqlServerController("(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB");
        SQL.CreateDatabse("BetaDB2");
        List<Column> ColumnList = new List<Column>();
        ColumnList.Add(SQL.CreateColumn("id", DataType.Int,"" ,true, false));
        ColumnList.Add(SQL.CreateColumn("name", DataType.NVarChar(50), "", false, false));
        ColumnList.Add(SQL.CreateColumn("UID", DataType.NVarChar(200), "", false, false));
        ColumnList.Add(SQL.CreateColumn("Pass", DataType.NVarChar(50), "", false, false));
        SQL.CreateTable("BetaDB2", "userha", ColumnList, null);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried internet? Your question is too broad for SO. I suggest you do some research on the internet first.

Comment: yes , but i could not find any thing that could do it with SMO